# Parsing numbers with pattern in Java without DecimalFormat

Tags: java, string-parsing

Is there a Java parsing library similar to `DecimalFormat`?  I am unable to do what I want with `DecimalFormat` and regular expressions.

I need to be able to:

- Parse only an integer (DecimalFormat needs more settings than just pattern)
- Parse decimal (precise no rounding)
- Parse numbers like 123,456.789. (DecimalFormat for ###,###.### accepts "123456789" as well)

Comment: What was wrong with trying to use a regular expression? What did you try?

Comment: You can combine a regular expression to check the strict rules with a DecimalFormat for simple conversion.

Comment: Regular expression is available when checking format but it doesn't provide the parsing capability. E.G. I can regexp check "123,456.789 $" but then I still need to parse it correctly.

Using both would mostly solve it however the process becomes complicated (the two different checks increase probability of error)

Comment: If you want to parse currency values you might want to have a look at [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @JanDrábek "Using both would mostly solve it however the process becomes complicated" - that's the way to go here. If you need strict validation, implement it using a tool that's good for validation. (Which regexps are.) For parsing, use the tool that's good for parsing. (`DecimalFormat`.) Just because there's some overlap between these in that a parser will reject input it can't make sense of doesn't mean it makes sense to have a single tool do both. (In fact, most web frameworks I've touched separate the concerns of input validation and input conversion, as inconvenient as that is.)

Comment: @millimoose it seems that there is no better way. So sad that there is no elegant way. It will also need more work to create patterns which would work in different locale too (Decimal comma etc) Thanks you anyway ;-)

Comment: @JanDrábek Java already comes with formatting patterns for many, many locales, you don't necessarily need to reinvent them from scratch.

Comment: @millimoose I know there is built-in support for many locales... I have no reinventing in plan... What formatting patterns do you have in mind?

Comment: @JanDrábek The kind you get using `NumberFormat.getInstance(someLocale)`, without having to write your own patterns.

Comment: @millimoose yes I am doing it this way, however it has limits I can't enforce input to be in certain format as I wrote in question. The regexp could solve it, but as far as I know I would have to write them on my own.

For example, I want to ensure that input field is in format "1 234 4567,3 Kč"... I can't do that with NumberFormat only. NumberFormat is too benevolent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try treating it like a String and tokenizing it.

str.split("\\.") will split out the decimal side and then substring it to your precision, then on the number side you could split(",")

This is quite a bit of manual parsing work though...

Comment: Yes, but with the need to support locale it becomes not so good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I **would** use Regexp and `NumberFormat`:

```
Map<Pattern,NumberFormat> POSSIBLE_FORMATS = ...;
String input = ...;
Number value = null;
for (Map.Entry<Pattern,NumberFormat> possible : POSSIBLE_FORMATS.entrySet()) {
  if (possible.getKey().matcher(input).matches()) {
    value = possible.getKeValue().parse(input);
    break;
  }
}
if (value == null) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentExcption("no valid input format: " + input);
}
```

Comment: As millimoose made a comment above, the way with regexp will be the way. However it has one weakness. How to solve locale problems? Preparing the pattern on the runtime from given locale?

Comment: Localized values are a problem. You may prepare the patterns using DecimalFormatSymbols.